# how to make tensorflow placeholder to work properly

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I wrote simple code using tensorflow. I thought the code below should work. The goal of this code is simple. Just calculating simple addition.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[35.0, 40.0, 45.0]]).astype(np.float32)
print np.shape(data)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3], name='x')
y = tf.Variable(x + 5, name='y')

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model)
    result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: data})
    print result
```

But, the interpreter says something like this;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "basic_compare.py", line 12, in <module>
sess.run(model)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [1,3]
 [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'x', defined at:
File "basic_compare.py", line 6, in <module>
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3], name='x')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1332, in placeholder
name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1748, in _placeholder
name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [1,3]
 [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

I just copied what is essential to the error. I am spending lots of hours for this simple code, but I don't see any problem. Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is something else essetntial to the error that you did not copy: the line in your script that causes the error. It is not the `sess.run(y ...` line but the initislization line - `sess.run(model)`. You are trying to initialize `y` with non-fed `x` value. The possible solution is to make `y` an op instead of a variable: `y = tf.sum(x, 5.0, name='y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `x` as a variable initializer, so you need to feed `x` when executing `tf.initialize_all_variables()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[35.0, 40.0, 45.0]]).astype(np.float32)
print np.shape(data)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3], name='x')
y = tf.Variable(x, name='y')

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model, feed_dict={x: data})
    result = sess.run(y)
    print result
```

Hope that helps!